# How should I explain the cpu usage of this application?

Tags: performance

OS : win7 64bits

I am measuring the cpu usage of an application, following are the results of the cpu usage

```
         Cpu 1   Cpu 2    Cpu 3    Cpu 4    Cpu 5    Cpu 6      Cpu 7     Cpu 8
Max      71.8    47.6     98.4     46.8     95.4     6.2        1.9       70.3
Min      3.5     0        0        0        10.8     0          0         4.3
Average  26.652  2.10272  33.2662  2.95886  50.3894  0.0659401  0.060218  30.8496
```

This application is a single thread program, yet when it is very busy, many cpu also looks busy. I don't know the reason of this, my guess is the os would put the application to different cpu to execute even it is a single thread program(move the thread to another cpu). Is this possible? Have I missed something?

Comment: Windows does this as well, even on an otherwise idle system. I never understood why the program is migrated between cores that often. Seems like unnecessary cache usage loss.